Can I use community ag-grid to do server side pagination
I am trying to use ag-grid community version to do server side pagination but I am getting that ag-grid-enterprise is required to use rowModelType = 'serverSide' setup
to use server side pagination I need to set rowModelType = 'serverSide'
but I am gettin the error that ag-grid-enterprise is required.
